# Memory leak in Core Graphics when clipping UIImage with UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I'm using the following Swift 3 code to crop a UIImage to a speech bubble shape. I'm finding that it leaks about 2MB every time it's run. If I comment out the createBubbleImage call, it no longer leaks. As you can see, I've tried adding an autoreleasepool, but it doesn't help. Any ideas?

```
import UIKit

class BubbleImageView: UIImageView {

  var bubbleImage : UIImage? {
    didSet {
      let path = SwipeCard.bubblePath(frame: self.bounds)
      DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        //background code
        let newImage = self.createBubbleImage(source: self.bubbleImage, path: path)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          //your main thread
          self.image = newImage
        }
      }
    }
  }

  fileprivate func createBubbleImage(source: UIImage?, path: UIBezierPath) -> UIImage? {
    var newImage : UIImage?
    autoreleasepool {
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, 0)
      path.addClip()
      source?.draw(in: self.bounds)
      newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
    return newImage
  }

  deinit {
    bubbleImage = nil
    image = nil
  }

}
```

Comment: Its probably because of your dispatchClosures. try `[weak self] _ in` after the opening bracket of dispatchQueue closures

Comment: I second JustineM.

Comment: I don't see where the dispatch closures/blocks would cause a retain cycle. Sure, they would retain self during their execution, but I don't see anything holding on to the closures/blocks after that point, so when the blocks are done they should release self again.

Comment: @JustinM thanks for the suggestion. Tried it but doesn't seem to make a difference. I'm not sure it makes sense that it would be retaining through the dispatch blocks -- they should be released after they're done.